# angular error in declaring multiple modules

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-directive

I m new to Angular JS (apologies if my my terminology is incorrect or not enough explained).

I m trying to do a demo creating multiple modules which are just returning messages. My domo has just 2 files, I m copying complete code below.

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['controllers1', 'controllers2']);

    angular.module('controllers1', []).controller('MainController', function($scope) {

        $scope.message1 = "controllers1 message";
        $scope.func1 = function () {
            return "controllers1 func";
        }

        }
    );

    angular.module('controllers2', []).controller('MainController2', function ($scope) {

        $scope.message2 = "controllers2 message";
        $scope.func2 = function () {
            return "controllers2 func";
        }

    }
    );
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/Index.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        {{2+2}}

        <div ng-controller="MainController1">
            {{message1}}
            {{func1()}}
            <br /><br/>

            <div ng-controller="MainController2">
                {{
                {{message2}}
                {{func2()}}
                }}
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Issue:**
If I create a just one module it works fine but if I create 2 modules it give weird error. Can you please guide me who to fix this error and create multiple modules and consume them.

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$parse/syntax?p0=message2&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=16&p3=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bmessage2&p4=message2
L/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:6:446
Ya.prototype.throwError@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:152:392
Ya.prototype.consume@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:153:338
Ya.prototype.object@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:161:34
Ya.prototype.primary@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:152:26
Ya.prototype.unary@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:158:114
Ya.prototype.multiplicative@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:158:1
Ya.prototype.additive@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:157:365
Ya.prototype.relational@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:157:1
Ya.prototype.equality@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:157:1
Ya.prototype.logicalAND@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:156:1
Ya.prototype.logicalOR@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:156:346
Ya.prototype.ternary@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:156:1
Ya.prototype.assignment@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:155:1
Ya.prototype.expression@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:155:369
Ya.prototype.filterChain@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:155:1
Ya.prototype.statements@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:154:292
Ya.prototype.parse@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:151:19
td/this.$get</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:89:450
f@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:72:89
t@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:56:1
oa@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:45:14
E@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:43:136
E@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:43:252
E@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:43:252
E@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:43:252
v@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:41:303
Wb/c/</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:17:455
wd/this.$get</g.prototype.$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:100:187
wd/this.$get</g.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:100:452
Wb/c/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:17:413
d@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:30:321
Wb/c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:17:321
Wb@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:18:23
Oc@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:17:96
@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:198:494
a@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:128:229
Uc/c/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:26:466
q@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:7:259
Uc/c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:26:439

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js
Line 83
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be declaring a `MainController` controller, but you reference `MainController1` in the `ng-controller` directive.

Try this line instead:

```
angular.module('controllers1', []).controller('MainController1', function($scope) {
```

Also, I don't get what you are trying to do with these lines of code:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController2">
    {{
        {{message2}}
        {{func2()}}
    }}
</div>
```

Try removing those extra brackets as shown below:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController2">
    {{message2}}
    {{func2()}}
</div>
```

If you open the provided link ([this one](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=message2&p1=is%20unexpected,%20expecting%20%5B:%5D&p2=16&p3=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bmessage2&p4=message2)) it shows the following message:

> Syntax Error: Token 'message2' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column
>   16 of the expression [
>               {{message2] starting at [message2].

So yes, the error is thrown because you are using an invalid expression in your HTML template.

Answer (score 1):

please check this working [CODE - PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/sZ9CD4EtnNKu5rLozjvI?p=preview)

problem you have is the curly brackets

```
      {{ //remove this
            {{message2}}
            {{func2()}}
      }} //remove this as well
```

also as danilo pointed out

```
angular.module('controllers1', [])
.controller('MainController1', function($scope) {
```

Comment: To expand on this, you can take the errors.angularjs.org link and open it in the browser to see the actual issue: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=message2&p1=is%20unexpected,%20expecting%20%5B:%5D&p2=16&p3=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bmessage2&p4=message2%20L%2F%3C@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.0

... which shows Syntax Error: Token 'message2' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 16 of the expression [
            {{message2] starting at [message2 L/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/ang....

Comment: @HarishR thanks, it worked. sorry I did not get you on "also as danilo pointed out" ? can you please explain it.

Comment: @haansi Check my answer. You'll understand.